# How to generate the CSR on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, csr

I'm going to buy a SSL in order to install it in my e-commerce.
I need to generate the CSR first before to buy the certification.

Anybody have a tutorial in order to generate the CSR?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to do with GCP. Follow any tutorial for the operating system you're using. You should consider **not** buying an SSL and using Let's Encrypt, which is free.

Comment: @ceejayoz Not quite so simple, alas; GCLB doesn't have a hook for Let's Encrypt, so you'd have to rotate the cert manually (or via a script), every 89 days at the absolute most -- and if anything happened to that script, the site would start throwing errors for users on day 91, since LE certs are only good for 90 days.

Comment: @Alex Isn't rotating the cert via a weekly/monthly script already the recommended practice for LE?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, but that's typically handled by certbot and a cron job — which won't update the GCLB. You'd have to write that logic yourself.

Comment: @Alex Ah, I understand what you're getting at now.

Comment: @ceejayoz This *would*, however, be doable with GCLB doing *network load balancing* on port 443, rather than HTTPS load balancing, and leaving the TLS termination on the instances (which would have certbot scheduled).

Answer (score 1):

Searching GCP's documentation for "[SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/s/results/?q=SSL+certificate&p=%2Fdocs%2F)" gives [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates#creating_an_ssl_certificate_resource) as the first result. I've further refined it to point to the exact section on that page for what you're asking.